# Beaker-Style Session in Python

Tags: python, security, session, python-3.x

Preface: I recently have been learning Python web development using simple CGI. I bet my Python teacher that he couldn't get into my database, or otherwise 'hack' my simple web application. Unfortunately, after teaching myself how to use certain modules in order to make my application secure, I learned that my web host (Hostgator) does not allow the installation of additional modules. The only one I haven't been able to work-around (due to it's complexity) is the Beaker cookie-less session. [Here](http://beaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/session.html#beaker.session.Session) is what I'm trying to recreate.

Here is a list of the available Python3 modules from Hostgator:

```
CDROM               atexit              importlib           shutil
DLFCN               audioop             inspect             signal
IN                  base64              io                  site
MySQLdb             bdb                 itertools           smtpd
TYPES               binascii            json                smtplib
__future__          binhex              keyword             sndhdr
_abcoll             bisect              lib2to3             socket
_ast                builtins            linecache           socketserver
_backport           bz2                 locale              spwd
_bisect             cProfile            logging             sqlite3
_codecs             calendar            macpath             sre_compile
_codecs_cn          cgi                 macurl2path         sre_constants
_codecs_hk          cgitb               mailbox             sre_parse
_codecs_iso2022     chunk               mailcap             ssl
_codecs_jp          cmath               marshal             stat
_codecs_kr          cmd                 math                string
_codecs_tw          code                mimetypes           stringprep
_collections        codecs              mmap                struct
_compat_pickle      codeop              modulefinder        subprocess
_csv                collections         multiprocessing     sunau
_ctypes             colorsys            netrc               symbol
_ctypes_test        command             nis                 symtable
_curses             compileall          nntplib             sys
_curses_panel       concurrent          ntpath              sysconfig
_datetime           configparser        nturl2path          syslog
_dbm                contextlib          numbers             tabnanny
_dummy_thread       copy                opcode              tarfile
_elementtree        copyreg             operator            telnetlib
_functools          crypt               optparse            tempfile
_gdbm               csv                 os                  termios
_hashlib            ctypes              os2emxpath          test
_heapq              curses              ossaudiodev         tests
_io                 datetime            parser              textwrap
_json               dbm                 pdb                 this
_locale             decimal             pickle              threading
_lsprof             difflib             pickletools         time
_markerlib          dis                 pip                 timeit
_markupbase         distutils           pipes               tkinter
_multibytecodec     doctest             pkg_resources       token
_multiprocessing    dummy_threading     pkgutil             tokenize
_mysql              easy_install        platform            trace
_mysql_exceptions   email               plistlib            traceback
_pickle             encodings           poplib              tty
_posixsubprocess    errno               posix               turtle
_pyio               fcntl               posixpath           turtledemo
_random             filecmp             pprint              types
_socket             fileinput           profile             unicodedata
_sqlite3            fnmatch             pstats              unittest
_sre                formatter           pty                 urllib
_ssl                fractions           pwd                 uu
_string             ftplib              py_compile          uuid
_strptime           functools           pyclbr              virtualenv
_struct             gc                  pydoc               virtualenv_support
_symtable           genericpath         pydoc_data          warnings
_testcapi           getopt              pyexpat             wave
_thread             getpass             queue               weakref
_threading_local    gettext             quopri              webbrowser
_tkinter            glob                random              wsgiref
_warnings           grp                 re                  xdrlib
_weakref            gzip                readline            xml
_weakrefset         hashlib             reprlib             xmlrpc
abc                 heapq               resource            xxlimited
aifc                hmac                rlcompleter         xxsubtype
antigravity         html                runpy               zipfile
argparse            http                sched               zipimport
array               idlelib             select              zlib
ast                 imaplib             setuptools
asynchat            imghdr              shelve
asyncore            imp                 shlex
```

(Sorry that it's so long, I just thought it was a relevant piece of information).

So, finally, with the question. How can I recreate the Beaker encrypted session management using only the modules listed? I could really use some help here, and I appreciate it greatly. Even if someone could point me (or better yet push me) in the right direction. Keep in mind that my goal is to block against cross-site scripting via an encrypted session id (or something similar).

As a side note, please let me know if this is NOT the ideal method. I would greatly appreciate the help.

**EDIT:**
I was able to get beaker installed onto the server by adding a PYTHONPATH and installing into a separate directory. However, I cannot install WSGI as it is (confirmed) not supported for Hostgator shared accounts. I have been trying to figure out how to either A: Use the Beaker module to manage my sessions without using WSGI -- it waits for the call to start_response to send the session information, and that only works with the WSGI format from what I can tell (I've tried it a couple of different ways without any success). Or B: Build a secure session management class from scratch (This seems too far out of reach for me to conquer.)

Comment: Do you mean that there is absolutely no way to somehow modify the HTTP(S) response headers?

Comment: You can always ship a copy of `Beaker` with your own code. But I would instead just switch to a decent hoster. https://www.pythonanywhere.com is supposed to be pretty good.

Comment: @BasicWolf -- I didn't know that's how Beaker was implementing it. (Sorry). Honestly I have only used libraries for session control up to this point and haven't lifted the hood to see how it works. I will start looking into this, I appreciate the heads up.

Comment: @LukasGraf -- Thank you for the recommendation, however I have already setup SSL with Hostgator and am not willing to switch hosts this deep into my project.